# Jasmine.createSpy equivalent in jest

Tags: jestjs, jasmine

I am migrating from jasmine to jest in my application. I have the following line to test

```
JSON.parse(window.document.querySelector(SELECTOR).innerHTML)
```

In my test I used jasmine.

```
document.querySelector = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.returnValue(dummyEl)
```

But now with jest I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a combination of `jest.fn` and `.mockReturnValue`.

I am not good with `jest` but I think it can be:

```
document.querySelector = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(dummyEl);
```

Check out the documentation here:

https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestfnimplementation

https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn

Comment: I used spy and it worked too.
jest.spyOn(document, 'querySelector').mockReturnValue(dummyEl);